# Find the ideal gas law from the internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, entropy, ideal-gas

I'm looking for a way on how to obtain the ideal gas law $PV=nRT$ by being given the internal energy $$U=U(S,V)=\alpha N k_b \left(\frac NV\right)^{2/3} e^{2S/(3Nk_b)}$$ I can find the pressure and the temperature both from $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_S=-P$$ and $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_V=T$$ but I don't know how to continue after? Other else than substituting $P$ and $T$ in $PV=nRT$ which is indeed a proof but it isn't really a rigorous proof since we are using our objetive to prove itself so, is there any other way?

Comment: What happens if you substitute your expression for $U$ into your equations for $P$ and $T$?

Comment: Why do you think plugging $P$ and $T$ into $P/T=\ldots$ would be not rigorous? Putt differently: Just compute $P/T$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not totally sure if this is the most straightforward way, but you will receive the ideal gas law by varying $U$, that is

$$\operatorname{d}U =  \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V} \operatorname{d}V + \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S}\operatorname{d}S$$.

Since you know that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}= -p$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}= T$, you can plug it into this equation and get

$$\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\operatorname{d}V + \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S} \operatorname{d}S = -p \operatorname{d}V + T\operatorname{d}S $$.

On the other hand you can carry out the derivatives on the left hand side, which will give you

$$\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V} = -\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha k_B \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{5/3}e^x$$

and

$$\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S} = \dfrac{2}{3}\alpha \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x$$

where $x=\frac{2S}{3Nk_b}$. Substituting again brings you to

$$-\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha k_B \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{5/3}e^x \operatorname{d}V + \dfrac{2}{3}\alpha \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x \operatorname{d}S = -p \operatorname{d}V + T\operatorname{d}S $$.

Rearranging gives

$$\Bigl( \dfrac{2}{3}\alpha \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x - T\Bigr) \operatorname{d}S = \Bigl( \dfrac{2}{3}\alpha k_B \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{5/3}e^x -p \Bigr)\operatorname{d}V$$.

Of course this equation needs to be true for all $\operatorname{d}V$ an $\operatorname{d}S$ and so

$$\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha k_B \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{5/3}e^x -p = 0$$

and

$$\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x - T = 0$$

needs to hold true. Rearranging the first of these two equations yields

$$p = \dfrac{2}{3}\alpha k_B \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{5/3}e^x = 
\underbrace{\Bigl(\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha  \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x \Bigr)}_T \dfrac{k_B N}{V}$$.

That $T = \frac{2}{3}\alpha  \Bigl(\frac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x$ indeed is true, we can see by rearranging the latter of these two equations for $T$. Continuing with

$$p = \underbrace{\Bigl(\dfrac{2}{3}\alpha  \Bigl(\dfrac{N}{V}\Bigr)^{2/3}e^x \Bigr)}_T \dfrac{k_B N}{V} = \dfrac{T k_B N}{V} $$,

it is easy to see that

$$pV =  N k_B T$$.

With $R= N_A k_B$, where $N_A$ is Avogadro's constant and $\frac{N}{N_A}=n$, where $n$ is the mole number and $N$ is the number of molecules, we finally found

$$pV =  n R T$$.